# Conditional tuning of hyperparameters with RandomizedSearchCV in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I want to use RandomizedSearchCV in sklearn to search for the optimal hyperparameter values for a support vector classifier on my dataset. The hyperparameters I am optimising are "kernel", "C" and "gamma". However, in the case of a "poly" kernel, I would also like to optimise a fourth hyperparameter, "degree" (the index of the polynomial kernel function).

I realise that since the degree hyperparameter is ignored when the kernel is not "poly", I could just include degree in the params dictionary I provide to RandomizedSearchCV (as I've done in the code below). However, ideally I would like to search uniformely across the non-poly kernels plus each degree of poly kernel, i.e. I want to sample uniformly across e.g. [(kernel="linear"), (kernel="rbf"), (kernel="poly", degree=2), (kernel="poly", degree=3)]. Therefore, I was wondering if it is possible to conditionally introduce a hyperparameter for tuning, i.e. if kernel="poly" degree=np.linspace(2, 5, 4), else degree=0.

I haven't been able to find an example of this in the RandomizedSearchCV documentation, and so was wondering if anybody here had come across the same issue and would be able to help. Thanks!

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

clf = SVC()
params = {'kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid'],
          'degree': np.linspace(2, 5, 4),
          'C': np.logspace(-3, 5, 17),
          'gamma': np.logspace(-3, 5, 17)}

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator=clf, param_distributions=params, n_iter=200, n_jobs=-1,
    cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5), iid=False
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [GridsearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) and [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) don't support conditional tuning of hyperparameters.

[Hyperopt](https://hyperopt.github.io) supports conditional tuning of hyperparameters, check this [wiki](https://github.com/jaberg/hyperopt/wiki/FMin) for more details.

**Example:**

```
space4svm = {
    'C': hp.uniform('C', 0, 20),
    'kernel': hp.choice('kernel', [
            {'ktype': 'linear'},
            {'ktype': 'poly', 'degree': hp.lognormal('degree', 0, 1)},
            ]),
    'gamma': hp.uniform('gamma', 0, 20),
    'scale': hp.choice('scale', [0, 1]),
    'normalize': hp.choice('normalize', [0, 1])
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can make conditional arguments for or within the gridsearch (it would feel like a useful feature). However, one solution to go around this, is to simply set all the hyperparameters for `randomizesearchcv` add make use of the `errors_raise` paramater, which will allow you to pass through the iterations that would normally fail and stop your process. Like this:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

clf = SVC()
params = {'kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid'],
          'degree': np.linspace(2, 5, 4),
          'C': np.logspace(-3, 5, 17),
          'gamma': np.logspace(-3, 5, 17)}

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator=clf, param_distributions=params, n_iter=200, n_jobs=-1,
    cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5), iid=False,errors_raise=0)
```

#### However

From [sklearn's SVC documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) you shouldn't have any problems passing `degree`:

> degree : int, optional (default=3)
>   Degree of the polynomial kernel function (‘poly’). Ignored by all other kernels.

Comment: I don't know if they changed it since the answer was given, but the parameter is called `error_score` (which is set to `"raise"` by default and you can pass any numeric value instead) and not `error_raise`.
It's the same for `GridSearchCV`, `RandomizedSearchCV` and `HalvingRandomSearchCV` and it works like a charm !

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will look into the documentation and my answer to edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Since conditional paramaters are not supported in `sklearn`, the random parameter search will optimize a search space which includes redundant combinations of parameters.** For example, there are already 289 combinations for `kernal=linear` for the given value ranges of `C` and `gamma`, adding `degree` will shoot this number up to 1156! In cases where model training takes a long time, you would want to omit these 867 useless combinations. The example below shows how you can provide your desired search space without any additional library.

```
n_c_values = len(np.logspace(-3, 5, 17))
n_gamma_values = len(np.logspace(-3, 5, 17))
n_degree_values = len(np.linspace(2, 5, 4))
print(n_c_values * n_gamma_values)
# 289
print(n_c_values * n_gamma_values * n_degree_values)
# 1156
```

`sklearn` allows us to pass multiple dictionaries of parameter grids to `RandomizedSearchCV` . **In the example above, we thereby reduce the amount of parameter combinations from `4624` (4 * 1156) to `2023`!**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

clf = SVC()

params = {'kernel': ['linear', 'rbf', 'sigmoid'],
          'C': np.logspace(-3, 5, 17),
          'gamma': np.logspace(-3, 5, 17)}

params_poly = {'kernel': ['poly'],
            'degree': np.linspace(2, 5, 4),
          'C': np.logspace(-3, 5, 17),
          'gamma': np.logspace(-3, 5, 17)}

param_grid = [params, params_poly]
# 2023 combinations

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator=clf, param_distributions=param_grid, n_iter=200, n_jobs=-1,
    cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
)
```